# Implementing logic from controller with javascript and ajax request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my Rails application, I add a certain user to the reader's list when he views a certain post.

**PostsController#Show**

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
if (current_user)
  @post.reader_links.create(reader_id: current_user.id)
end
```

However, I want to implement this from the client side, using javascript and ajax request. The feature will be slightly changed so that the user will be added to the list ONLY when he **types into a certain form(presses a key).**

So the original code will be replaced by the following code in **posts/show.erb.html**

```
function typeCatch(){
  $(this).off("keypress",typeCatch)//remove handler
  //I WANT TO ADD THE USER TO THE LIST AT THIS POINT
}

$("#field_id").on("keypress",typeCatch)
```

I need some help to implement the original feature in javascript and posting through ajax request. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Emm... <% @post.reader_links.create(reader_id: current_user.id) %> inside javascript function within .erb file?

Comment: Will this help? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/

Or this? http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in this lines:

```
# on a controller
def update_links
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if (current_user)
    @post.reader_links.create(reader_id: current_user.id)
  end
end


// on your javascript
function typeCatch(){
  $(this).off("keypress",typeCatch)//remove handler
  $.post('/path/to/controller/post_id/action')
 }

 $("#field_id").on("keypress",typeCatch)
```

Note that the javascript should not be the answer of your new action, but must be in the page that triggers the event of creating a new reader link.

If you have no idea of what you are doing, I recommend reading the links that @FlufflyJack commented in your question

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a ton! I also understand unobtrusive ajax request much better than before just by dealing with this example